# JS Объединение двух массивов c заменой первого элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть два массива:

```
const seoDaysWeek = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"];
const workTime = ["Пн. 8:00 — 20:00", "Вт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Ср. 8:00 — 20:00","Чт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Пт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Сб. 8:00 — 20:00", "Вс. 8:00 — 20:00"]
```

Должно получится:

```
arr = ["Mo 8:00 — 20:00", "Tu 8:00 — 20:00", "We 8:00 — 20:00", "Th 8:00 — 20:00", "Fr 8:00 — 20:00", "Sa 8:00 — 20:00", "Su 8:00 — 20:00"]
```

Пробовал через map, но очень странно объединяет.

```js
const seoDaysWeek = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"];
const workTime = ["Пн. 8:00 — 20:00", "Вт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Ср. 8:00 — 20:00","Чт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Пт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Сб. 8:00 — 20:00", "Вс. 8:00 — 20:00"]
const arr = seoDaysWeek.map((item, i) => ({
            ...item,
            ...workTime[i],
        })
    );
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Т.е. по факту русское сокращение надо заменить на английское?

Comment: Ну по факту да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const seoDaysWeek = {"Пн.": "Mo", "Вт.": "Tu", "Ср.": "We", "Чт.": "Th", "Пт.": "Fr", "Сб.": "Sa", "Вс.": "Su"};
const workTime = ["Пн. 8:00 — 20:00", "Вт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Ср. 8:00 — 20:00","Чт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Пт. 8:00 — 20:00", "Сб. 8:00 — 20:00", "Вс. 8:00 — 20:00"]

const result = workTime.map(element => {
    let repleceStr = element.substr(0, 3);    
    element = element.replace(repleceStr, seoDaysWeek[repleceStr]);
    
    return element;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо большое. А то часа 3 мучался.